# browse another path without changing the browser url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a web app hosted at `www.domain.com/app/dir/`

The app url would be something like `www.domain.com/app/dir/?p=dashboard/`

Now, I have a situation, where I need to use an unique key in the url (which I can't use as query string).

So what I need is the users will browse the web app using different urls, like :

```
www.domain.com/user1/dir/?p=dashboard/
www.domain.com/user2/dir/?p=dashboard/
www.domain.com/user3/dir/?p=dashboard/
```

But I need to browse the files in `www.domain.com/app/dir/?p=dashboard/` when the user visits the above link (without changing the browser url).

Note :  the directories user1, user2, user3 doesn't exist

Comment: Is "dir" in `/app/dir/` different or the same as "dir" in `/user1/dir/`? Is "dir" variable?

Comment: @MrWhite There is no directory named `user1`. `/app/dir/` is the actual directory, where the files are stored (dir is a subfolder inside app folder). What I want is to redirect `/user1/dir/` to `/app/dir/` without changing the url.

Comment: Yes, my answer below would seem to cover the points you've raised in your question. Although you've used the same text "dir" in both the source and destination - but these are unrelated, yes? Note that this is a "rewrite", not "redirect" - in order to preserve the URL in the browser. Although your comment appears to suggest you need to rewrite `/user1/dir/<url-path>` to `/app/dir/<url-path>` - is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to change only url without page refresh:**
*This method is pure javascript*

```
window.history.pushState('', '', 'enter_here_your_url');
```

**If you want to load page without page refresh:**
*This is JQuery*

```
$("body").load("enter_here_your_page_url");
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am looking for. I need a server side solution, when a user visits `/user1/dir/` (which actually doesn't exist), I need to forward them to `/app/dir/` without changing the url (i.e, the browser should still show `/user1/dir/`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to *internally rewrite* the URL from `/<user>/dir/?p=dashboard/` to `/app/dir/index.php` - which I assume is what the actual end-point is, rather than `/app/dir/` - which would require mod_dir to issue a secondary subrequest for the DirectoryIndex.

I'll assume that `<user1>` can consist of any word character, include a hyphen. In other words `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEgnine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=dashboard$
RewriteRule ^\w+/dir/$ /app/dir/index.php [L]
```

You can extract the `<user1>` (first URL-path segment) by examining the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable in PHP.